# KMC Z7 chain for 8 speed cassete

Tags: chain, cassette, derailleur-rear

#### Can I use [KMC Z7 chaing](https://www.kmcchain.com/en/product/bicycle-chain-z7-7-speed)  (1/2 x 3/32) on 8 speed cassete [Sunrace MFM-56](http://www.sunrace.com/en/products/detail/mfm56)?

When I changed the old chain with KMC Z7, the smallest sprocket and the largest are fine.

But in the between the shifting is not smooth and something feels not right (slipping/ skiping). **NOTE**: chain and cassete are both new.

Below are picture of KMC Z7 and Sunrace MFM-56.

[image: KMC Z7]
[image: Sunrace MFM-56]

P.S. There is also Z8 chain on KMC website. But it seems to me, that it absolutely the same size (1/2 x 3/32, pin=7.3mm).

**UPDATE:**

I tried a new KMC Z8 chain with width of 7.1mm.
But it didn't provide a significant improvement.
Maybe there is something wrong with a cassete ( a fake one?).

Comment: I agree, but he both chain and cassette are new.

Answer (score 1):

Z7 is one of if not the only 7-speed specific chains still made. It won't work right on 8-speed.

Comment: But the Z8 has the same sizes? What the difference?

Comment: There's ambiguity in what one reads about this and I don't claim to know the chronology or have done all the measuring needed to see how it actually works firsthand, but basically in practice 7.1mm corresponds to 8-speed more and 7.3 to 7-speed. KMC lists the 7.3mm Missinglink as being compatible with a bunch of 8-speed chains, but then you go to put it on one and it's usually totally sloppy and the 7.1 fits better. Measure a bunch of 8-speed pin lengths and you'll be seeing 7.1-7.2, and I think the Z7 will be 7.3-7.4.

Comment: According to Wikipedia 6, 7 and 8 speed chains have the same dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain

Comment: @Carel I saw that. It's wrong. 6 speed chains originally had longer pins than 7.3/7.1 and 7-speed specific chains are not 7.1mm. Something went wrong in the data they're presenting. Look at old Sutherlands editions and you'll see.

Comment: @NathanKnutson KMC Z8.3 writes, that it has a 7.3 mm pin....
https://neweracycle.com/kmc-z8-3-for-6-7-8-speed-chain
I will try to buy a Shimano HG-40, which should be fine for 8 speed bike and will update... Also at cassette specs (http://www.sunrace.com/files/catalog/files/475/Specifications%20-%20Freewheels%20MTB.pdf) it says, that it should be compatible for 7.1-7.3 mm pin...

Comment: @NathanKnutson, you right. I measure the previous chain and it was 7mm width.
But what it's strange that in Sunrace specs it says, that it should be fine with 7.1-7.3 mm.